# Seleccionar dia de Month Calendar y mostrar fila DataGridView #C

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hola estoy hacien un proyecto donde cargo un datagridview con 30 días supongamos, y luego tengo un Month Calendar, ahí selecciono la fecha y me lleva a la fecha seleccionada mostrandomela en el DataGridView. Pero me da este problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime fecha = DateTime.Today;

        int d = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
        int s = d - 1;
        dataGridView1.Rows[s].Selected = true;
        
    }
```

Necesito ayuda para que me funcione como debería, desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

el error que muestra es que la cadena no es válida para convertirla en string, eso es xq el método `ToShortDateString` devuelve un string en este formato `6/1/2009` es decir no se puede parsear a string me imagino que lo que quieras sea tomar el valor del mes para esto puede usar las propiedad `Month` o si quiere el día use la propiedad `Day` ejemplo `(DateTime.Today.Month o DateTime.Today.Month)`, ahora me imagino que no quiera usar la fecha actual si no la fecha que se seleccionó en el `monthCalendar1` para eso debe acceder a `monthCalendar1.SelectionStart` eso es un `DateTime` con el valor de la selección y puede acceder al mes y el día, de todos modos le dejo estas doc https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0 y https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.datechanged?view=net-5.0#examples Saludos

Answer (score 0):

No estabas tomando el valor de la fecha que seleccionaste, ademas si ya tienes la fecha puedes extraer el dia con .Day

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime Fecha = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart;
    int s = Fecha.Day - 1;
    dataGridView1.Rows[s].Selected = true;
}
```